# Not returning to the initial activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I want to select a text file on my mobile and upload it to Mysql Server. For that I am creating an intent-:

```
             public void chooseImage(View v){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("file/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);

                }
```

Then I am using onActivityResult-:

```
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    if(requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null)
                    {
                        Uri selected_file = data.getData();
                        Log.i("TAG2","Data is there");
                    }
                    Log.i("TAG2","Data is not there");
                }
```

But when I choose a button , it shows SD card and that is all right but after that when I go to a file and click it nothing happens, I thought I will be returned to my app but no matter how many times I click nothing is happening, it is not returning to my app. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. logging it in correct way:

> ```
> if(requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null)
> {
>    Uri selected_file = data.getData();
>    Log.i("TAG2","Data is there");
> }
> else//<--
> {
>        Log.i("TAG2","Data is not there");
> }
> ```

2. Use different app to choose file. It works correctly on my tablet.
3. It could be Android bug in old versions.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16362

Which android version do you use?

Comment: I think you have problem with the running app, which should finish itself, when you choose file.